# Crystal Reports 2010 in IIS 7.5 asking for authentication

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports-2010

We're in the process of moving from 2003 IIS6 Web servers to 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5.

We also have a Windows 2008 server running IIS7 and everything works fine on this server.

On the new servers when we go to our crystal reports viewer page we get prompted for windows authentication, then if you type in valid credentials or not you get the following error in firefox:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found
>
> Location: `http://192.168.10.112/Reports/ReportViewer.aspx?id=49`
>
> Line Number 1, Column 1:
>
> ^

In IE you just get a blank screen.

The same code runs fine in debug mode on the server in Visual Studio 2010, and works fine on our other servers

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that the answer is too late, but to be a reference for other users.

I faced this problem too in IIS 7.5, and after 5 days investigation, I found that the problem is because the Crystal Reports Viewer running as 32-bit, to solve this issue:

- in IIS, go to Application Pools
- Select pool that you are using it for your application, normally its "ASP.Net v4.0".
- Click on "Advanced Setting..." in the right panel.
- set the value "Enable 32-bit Application" to "True"

Also, note that you have to install the oracle client 32-bit version too.

Comment: In the end we found that if you ran the site using SSL it worked. So if we'd put it on our Live server it would of been fine, teaches me for putting it in a test environment first